# USPS Zip Code Zone Information

Tags: data, zip-codes, postal-code, usps

I'm trying to display USPS Shipping Zone information but the section of the USPS site I used to scrape this information from has been broken for months and I'm wondering if anyone knows another way to get it in a parsable format?

The page that has been broken for months is here: http://postcalc.usps.gov/Zonecharts/ZoneChartPrintable.aspx?zipcode=931

They have the same chart in a not-so-parsable format here: http://postcalc.usps.gov/Zonecharts/

I do cache this information so it doesn't have to be requested constantly, but the cache is cleared occasionally since the zones do change from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code that I use to fetch the JSON data that populates http://postcalc.usps.gov/Zonecharts/.

```
private String getZoneJSON(String zip3Digit) {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection con;
    String zoneJSON = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("https://postcalc.usps.com/DomesticZoneChart/GetZoneChart?ZIPCode3Digit=" + zip3Digit + "&ExcelFormat=1");
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
        con.setRequestProperty("DNT", "1");
        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        InputStream h = (InputStream) con.getContent();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(h));
        zoneJSON = r.readLine();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return zoneJSON;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. I hadn't been back to review their new site in a while but am glad they serve up a JSON string now instead of having to parse the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The USPS sells a full zone chart for all from-to zip combinations for $63 here: https://postalpro.usps.com/operations/zone-charts

I sent in for one since I haven't been able to find info this anywhere else for months now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also calculate the zone based on the distance between the coordinates origin SCF (Sectional Center Facility) and the destination SCF

Zone 1: Non-local zones within a 50 mile radius of the point of origination

Zone 2: 51-150 miles radius

Zone 3: 151-300 miles radius

Zone 4: 301-600 miles radius

Zone 5: 601-1,000 miles radius

Zone 6: 1001-1400 miles radius

Zone 7: 1401-1800 miles radius

Zone 8: 1801 miles and over

Zone 9: ZIP codes assigned for exceptional network circumstances

- You can fine the SCF for each zip code here: https://fast.usps.com/fast/fastApp/resources/labelListFiles.action
- You can get the coordinates of the SCF from Google API
- Once you have the coordinates, there are plenty of ways to calculate the distance between them
- You can also skip the coordinates and just calculate the distance between the zip codes of the SCF iteself (not the zip codes it serves)